# Chrome - disable web security - cant open file

Tags: google-chrome

When i open Chrome by cmd command -disable-web-security its open new blank chrome page where is written You are using unsupported command-line flag etc... Thats good !

But when i try to open index.html via chrome this error will shown  : Google Chrome is unresponsive . Relaunch now.... So how can i open any file with chrome disabled web security ? Please help ! Thx very mutch for any help !

I trying to connect tablet and Samsung Smart TV via [this](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00024/index.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you attempting to access files locally (ie, not through the web)? If so, you'll probably also need to add --allow-file-access-from-files flag as an argument when opening chrome through the command line.

Also, it may help to know the version of Chrome you're using as well as the OS it's running under -- could you please provide that if my suggestion didn't end up helping you?